# Uniqueness of measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I'm studying the Lebesgue-Besicovitch differentiation theorem (on the book "Sets of finite perimeter and geometrical variational problem- Maggi") but I'm not able to understand the following:

Why the decomposition of the measure is unique?How I can argue about this?

Comment: What decomposition?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $D_{\mu}\nu$ is defined μ-a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $D_{\mu}\nu \in L^1_{loc}( \mathbb{R}^n,\mu)$
and, in fact, $D_{\mu}\nu$ is Borel measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore,
$\nu = (D_{\mu}\nu) \mu + \nu^s_{\mu}$
on $M(μ)$
where the Radon measure $\nu^s_{\mu}$ 
is concentrated on the Borel set....
In particular, $\nu^s_{\mu}⊥ \mu$

Comment: The Lebesgue (Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym) decomposition. Uniqueness is trivial. First show this: If $\lambda<<m$ and also $\lambda\perp m$ then $\lambda=0$. Now say you have two decompositions of some measure. Subtract this from one side and that from the other side and you get a singular measure equal to an absolutely continuous measure...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you.